# Ubuntu 15.04 freezes for a second every 6-10 seconds, PCI/Radeon related messages in kern.log

Tags: freeze, 15.04, vgaswitcheroo, pci, i915

Tonight I made a fresh install of **Xubuntu 15.04** on my laptop, an Acer Aspire TimelineX 4820TG. I was running 14.04 LTS before, and all was fine. I didn't have lot of stuffs to save, so I went for a complete uninstall and fresh re-installation, in order to have a cleaner system.

Unfortunately I'm experiencing periodical freezes since first boot. **The freeze occurs every 6-10 seconds and lasts about 1 second.** During freeze mouse and keyboard are not responsive, and so it looks all the system. It is very annoying.

Additionally, I can hear fan speeds up every time the freeze occurs. And system hangs on shutdown (I had to long-press the power button).

I noticed that during *every* freeze these exact lines in `/var/log/kern.log` are printed:

```
[  159.876643] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling via VGA-switcheroo
[  160.097085] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Cannot lock devices!
[  160.844851] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  160.844866] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  160.844874] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  160.844884] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  160.844891] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  161.686549] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000000025E000).
[  161.686692] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[  161.686698] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800a7c78c00
[  161.686702] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800a7c78c0c
[  161.687450] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c418 and cpu addr 0xffffc9001a21c418
[  161.704183] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[  161.704196] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 2 usecs
[  161.880223] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[  161.880231] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[  161.880275] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  161.880313] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  162.030450] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[  162.048802] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Enabling via VGA-switcheroo
[  162.063426] [drm] radeon: finishing device.
[  162.072813] [TTM] Finalizing pool allocator
[  162.072823] [TTM] Finalizing DMA pool allocator
[  162.072976] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Used memory at exit: 0 kiB
[  162.072983] [drm] radeon: ttm finalized
[  162.072991] vga_switcheroo: disabled
[  162.073830] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=none,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[  162.116658] pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: [bus 01] is released
[  162.144719] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[  162.144741] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  162.144749] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  162.144756] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  162.144763] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  162.144769] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  162.145274] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  162.145280] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  162.145285] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  162.145293] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  162.145300] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  162.145373] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  162.145378] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  162.145384] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  162.145392] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  162.145398] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  162.145466] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  162.145471] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  162.145476] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  162.145485] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  162.145491] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  162.145518] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  162.145523] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  162.145528] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  162.145536] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  162.145542] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  162.145731] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
[  162.145772] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
[  162.145789] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  162.145795] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  162.145800] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  162.145808] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  162.145813] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  162.146003] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  162.146007] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  162.146012] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  162.146018] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  162.146023] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  162.146175] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[  162.146196] pci 0000:00:01.0: [8086:0045] type 01 class 0x060400
[  162.146242] pci 0000:00:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[  162.146501] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1002:68e0] type 00 class 0x030000
[  162.146521] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xe0000000-0xe7ffffff 64bit pref]
[  162.146533] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xdc400000-0xdc41ffff 64bit]
[  162.146541] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x20: [io  0x5000-0x50ff]
[  162.146554] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfffe0000-0xffffffff pref]
[  162.146593] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2
[  162.146665] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:01:00.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=none,locks=none
[  162.146669] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[  162.146700] pci 0000:01:00.1: [1002:aa68] type 00 class 0x040300
[  162.146718] pci 0000:01:00.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xdc420000-0xdc423fff 64bit]
[  162.146786] pci 0000:01:00.1: supports D1 D2
[  162.146830] pci 0000:01:00.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  162.146899] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[  162.146904] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
[  162.146908] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdc400000-0xdc4fffff]
[  162.146914] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff 64bit pref]
[  162.146921] pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
[  162.146930] pci 0000:01:00.0: can't claim BAR 6 [mem 0xfffe0000-0xffffffff pref]: no compatible bridge window
[  162.146936] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  162.146941] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  162.146945] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  162.146951] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  162.146956] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  162.146967] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xdc440000-0xdc45ffff pref]
[  162.146970] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[  162.146972] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
[  162.146975] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdc400000-0xdc4fffff]
[  162.146978] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff 64bit pref]
[  162.147669] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (CEDAR 0x1002:0x68E0 0x1025:0x0359).
[  162.147692] [drm] register mmio base: 0xDC400000
[  162.147694] [drm] register mmio size: 131072
[  162.147697] vga_switcheroo: enabled
[  162.147758] ATPX version 1, functions 0x000000bf
[  162.179303] ATOM BIOS: Acer
[  162.179384] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF (512M used)
[  162.179387] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000020000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
[  162.179389] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=512M, BAR=128M
[  162.179390] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[  162.179491] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 1856954 kiB
[  162.179493] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[  162.179497] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[  162.179521] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[  162.179522] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[  162.179535] [drm] Loading CEDAR Microcode
[  162.179542] [drm] Internal thermal controller with fan control
[  162.184385] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[  162.184499] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[  162.187590] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000000025E000).
[  162.187739] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[  162.187743] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff880099009c00
[  162.187745] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff880099009c0c
[  162.188678] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c418 and cpu addr 0xffffc90019f9c418
[  162.188688] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[  162.188689] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[  162.188691] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[  162.188731] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[  162.188759] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[  162.205589] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 2 usecs
[  162.205600] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 5 usecs
[  162.381860] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 2 usecs
[  162.381871] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[  162.382330] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  162.382380] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  163.032446] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[  163.037787] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[  163.037791] [drm] Connector 0:
[  163.037793] [drm]   LVDS-2
[  163.037796] [drm]   DDC: 0x6460 0x6460 0x6464 0x6464 0x6468 0x6468 0x646c 0x646c
[  163.037797] [drm]   Encoders:
[  163.037799] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[  163.037801] [drm] Connector 1:
[  163.037802] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[  163.037804] [drm]   HPD1
[  163.037807] [drm]   DDC: 0x6430 0x6430 0x6434 0x6434 0x6438 0x6438 0x643c 0x643c
[  163.037808] [drm]   Encoders:
[  163.037810] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY1
[  163.037811] [drm] Connector 2:
[  163.037813] [drm]   VGA-2
[  163.037816] [drm]   DDC: 0x64d8 0x64d8 0x64dc 0x64dc 0x64e0 0x64e0 0x64e4 0x64e4
[  163.037817] [drm]   Encoders:
[  163.037819] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[  163.156621] radeon 0000:01:00.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
[  163.156628] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1024x768
[  163.157939] [drm] fb mappable at 0xE045F000
[  163.157941] [drm] vram apper at 0xE0000000
[  163.157941] [drm] size 3145728
[  163.157942] [drm] fb depth is 24
[  163.157943] [drm]    pitch is 4096
[  163.158075] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb1: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[  163.158237] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.40.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 2
[  163.158403] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[  163.158605] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[  163.158623] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  163.158632] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  163.158638] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  163.158645] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  163.158651] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  163.159292] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  163.159303] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  163.159310] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  163.159321] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  163.159330] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  163.159432] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  163.159438] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  163.159444] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  163.159454] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  163.159463] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  163.159562] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  163.159570] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  163.159577] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  163.159588] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  163.159596] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  163.159633] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  163.159639] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  163.159646] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  163.159655] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  163.159665] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  163.159912] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
[  163.159961] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
[  163.159983] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  163.159990] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  163.159997] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[  163.160008] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff]
[  163.160016] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[  163.164586] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input36
```

Searching for similar messages, I came across some tips, and I ended up trying boot option `pci=noacpi` first and `noacpi` later. **They solve the problem**, but unfortunately both make my USB mouse not working (I didn't tested for other external USB devices).

What's the problem here? Why 12.04 works flawlessly? How can I solve it while keep my mouse and other USB devices working?

Thank you.

---

**UPDATE**: After further researches, I found it can be related to the double switchable graphics on my laptop, which looks broken on 15.04 updated kernel:

> https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88927
>   https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79701

I solved with the `radeon.runpm=0` boot option, but now dynamic turn on/off of the discrete graphic card is not working, so my system is hotter and battery life is shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reporting my issue on the Xorg and the Linux kernel Bugzilla, I was invited to test a kernel patch ([this is the patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=169601&action=diff), posted for [this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61891)).

After compiling and installing the patched kernel, the problem looks gone, and the dynamic turn on/off of the discrete graphic card is working again.

I have to thanks kernel developers for pointing me to the right direction, but unfortunately this is not a quick and easy solution. I hope they can ship the fix soon in next kernel releases.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with Ubuntu 15.04. Solved it by removing `psensors` with

```
sudo apt-get remove psensors
```

Comment: I don't have the `psensors` package installed.